# Can't use flatMap as an extension method on a self-written instance of a monad

Tags: scala, scala-cats, dotty, scala-3

I've tried to use flatMap on WriterT and it was successful.

So the problem is with my type probably but I can't find what's wrong with it.

```scala
import cats.Monad
import cats.syntax.flatMap._

object Main extends App {
    type Optional[A] = A | Null
    
    val maybeInt1: Optional[Int] = 1
    val maybeInt2: Optional[Int] = null
    
    given Monad[Optional] with {
        def pure[A](x: A): Optional[A] = x
        def flatMap[A, B](fa: Optional[A])(f: A => Optional[B]): Optional[B] = {
            fa match {
                case null => null
                case a: A => f(a)
            }
        }
        def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Optional[Either[A, B]]): Optional[B] = {
            f(a) match {
                case null     => null
                case Left(a1) => tailRecM(a1)(f)
                case Right(b) => b
            }
        }
    }

    def f[F[_]: Monad, A, B](a: F[A], b: F[B]) = a.flatMap(_ => b)
    
    println(Monad[Optional].flatMap(maybeInt1)(_ => maybeInt2)) //OK: null
    println(f[Optional, Int, Int](maybeInt1, maybeInt2)) // OK: null
    println(maybeInt1.flatMap(_ => maybeInt2)) // Compilation Error
}
```

The error is:

> value flatMap is not a member of Main.Optional[Int]. 
> An extension method was tried, but could not be fully constructed: 
> cats.syntax.flatMap.toFlatMapOps([A] =>> Any), A(given_Monad_Optional)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your definition has several issues.

#### Issue 1. You are using non-opaque type alias to a non-parametric type

I.e. `type Optional[A] = A | Null` is a type expression that will be expanded as soon as possible.
When you are using it as a result type what you actually get is

```scala
val maybeInt1: Int | Null = 1
val maybeInt2: Int | Null = null
```

So when the compile compiler has something like

```scala
implicit def toFlatMapOps[F[_], A](fa: F[A])(implicit F: Monad[F]): MonadOps[F, A]
```

imported from scala 2 library or equivalent extension in scala 3,
and finally comes to `maybeOption.flatMap`,
then tries to apply former extension method,
it fails to typecheck the expression
`toFlatMapOps(maybeInt1).flatMap(_ => maybeInt2)`

So now you have `Int | Null` as an argument since `Optional` have been already expanded and need to calculate corresponding `F[_]` and `A`, it has many solutions such as

1. `F[X] = Int | X , A = Null`
2. `F[X] = X | Null, A = Int`
3. `F[X] = A | Null, A = Nothing`
4. `F[X] = [X] =>> X, A = Int | Null`

So scala naturally fails this attempt to guess.

Despite that scala 3 compiler can use additional information such as implicit\contextual value here, the implicit value matching `Monad` with the highest priority here is

```scala
    given Monad[Optional]
```

Now can can attempt to apply
toFlatMapOps[F = Maybe](maybeInt1 : Int | Null)
Then having `F[X] = X | Null` you need to calculate the `A` knowing that `F[A] = Null | A` and that has many plausible solutions as well

1. `A = Int`
2. `A = Int | Null`

So even if scala wouldn't fail at the first step it'd stuck here

#### Solution 1. Use Opaque Type Aliases

Add `scalacOptions += "-Yexplicit-nulls"` to your sbt config and try this code

```scala
import cats.Monad
import cats.syntax.flatMap.given

object Optional:
  opaque type Optional[+A] >: A | Null = A | Null

  extension [A] (oa: Optional[A]) def value : A | Null = oa

  given Monad[Optional] with 
    def pure[A](x: A): Optional[A] = x
    def flatMap[A, B](fa: A | Null)(f: A => B | Null) = 
      if fa == null then null else f(fa)       
    def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => Optional[Either[A, B]]): Optional[B] = 
        f(a) match 
            case null     => null
            case Left(a1) => tailRecM(a1)(f)
            case Right(b) => b

type Optional[+A] = Optional.Optional[A]   

@main def run =    
    val maybeInt1: Optional[Int] = 1
    val maybeInt2: Optional[Int] = null   

    def f[F[_]: Monad, A, B](a: F[A], b: F[B]) = a.flatMap(_ => b)
    
    println(Monad[Optional].flatMap(maybeInt1)(_ => maybeInt2)) //OK: null
    println(f(maybeInt1, maybeInt2)) // OK: null
    println(maybeInt1.flatMap(_ => maybeInt2)) // Compilation Error
```

#### Issue 2. This type is not a monad

Even in this fixed version `Optional[A]` fails basic monadic laws
Consider this code

```scala
def orElse[F[_], A](fa: F[Optional[A]])(default: => F[A])(using F: Monad[F]): F[A] = 
    fa.map(_.value).flatMap(fb => if fb == null then default else F.pure(fb : A))   

def filterOne(x: Int): Optional[Int] = if x == 1 then null else x - 1

println(orElse(maybeInt1.map(filterOne))(3))
```

The first method attempts to resolve missing values with the given calculated monadic value, the second just filter out ones.
So, what do we expect to see when something like this evaluated?

```scala
orElse(maybeInt1.map(filterOne))(3)
```

We take non-empty maybe, then replacing the `1` with the missing place, and then immediately fixing it using provided `3`. So I would expect to see `3` but actually, we gain `null` as result since `null` inside the wrapped value considering as a missing branch for outer `Optional` during flatMap.
This is because such naively defined type violates the [left-identity law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Definition)

**UPDATE**
Regarding [comment by @n-pronouns-m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66846950/cant-use-flatmap-as-an-extension-method-on-a-self-written-instance-of-a-monad/66938818#comment118324965_66938818)
How this definition violates left identity law.
Left identity states that

```
pure(a).flatMap(f) == f(a) 
for all types A, B, and values a: A, f: A => Optional[B]
```

so lets take A = Optional[Int], B = Int, A = null, f(a) = if a == null then 3 else 2

pure(a) is still null, flatMap returns null for every in first argument, so
`pure(a).flatMap(f) == null` while `f(a) == 3`

Comment: The left identity law is stated in terms of unit, bind and another function f. If I am mot mistaken that would be flatMap(pure(a))(f) = f(a). It isn't quite clear from your example which f would violate this equality. filterOnes doesn't seem to.

Comment: `pure(a)` is `a` and not `null`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. we deliberately set a = null in this counterexample

Answer (score 1):

Odersky's [response](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/11981#issuecomment-813014495) on topic

> It does work if you make Null a separate class, or you compile with
> -Yexplicit-nulls.
>
> The way things are Null is a bottom type. So every class instance of
> Optional[C] is in fact C.
>
> I tried to change the definition of Optional to
>
> `type Optional[A] = A`
>
> then the implicit is not found either. So the
> problem looks like not a problem with union types at all. If
> Optional[A] defines a real union it works. It looks rather like a
> limitation of HK type inference that it cannot infer identities.
> That's actually expected, I think.